# Looking for for the title of a book with secret government experiments and talking monkeys

Tags: story-identification, books

The book starts with a guy’s father dying, then being taken from the morgue to a secret place. The guy follows and later discovers scientific experiments where there are talking monkeys. Along the way, he is being chased for having discovered the secret place, and everywhere he goes, people are being killed as the government people are trying to get to him.